# Create payload from array

Tags: php, string

I am trying to create the payload/data using an PHP array as input, by using [json_encode]. I noticed that the results of payload_1 has squared brackets but that payload_2 does not.

**Question:**

How can I create payload_2 with the result of squared brackets in the same position as in payload_1 ? To clarify, the outcome of payload_2 should be same as outcome of payload_1.

```
<?php

// Create payload from string.

$payload_1 = "{
    \"prenumeration\":
    [
        {
            \"url\":\"http://www.google.com\"
        }
    ]

}";

var_dump($payload_1);

echo "\n\n";

// Create payload from array.

$payload_2 = array(
    "prenumeration" => array(
    "url"           => "http://www.google.com"
    )
);

$payload_2 = json_encode($payload_2);

var_dump($payload_2);

echo "\n\n";
```

Results:

**Result (payload_1):**

```
"{"prenumeration":[{"url":"http://www.google.com"}]}"
```

**Result (payload_2):**

```
"{"prenumeration":{"url":"http:\/\/www.google.com"}}"
```

Comment: `$str = '{"prenumeration":[{"url":"http://www.google.com"}]}';

print_r(json_decode($str, true));`

Comment: The startpoint should be an array.

Comment: That code will give you array you need

Comment: That is correct, but only difference of the outcome compared to running payload_1, is that you do not escape the quoation marks, which is solved by [jso_decode]. My question is if it is possible to start with an array and construct the end-result.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8e24dec31ef0f02594f4bcd1d8284b36edc4ac2d

Comment: @splash58 This results in correct string and I have verfified that the http request can be sent and I get 200 ok. If you move you code to an answer, I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
$payload_2 = array(
    "prenumeration" => array(array(
        "url"           => "http://www.google.com"
    ))
);
```

`prenumeration` must be an array of associative arrays.

`array("url" => "http://www.google.com")` is an associative array of one element. Associative arrays are represented with curly brackets.

`array(array("url" => "http://www.google.com"))` is an array of one element (that happens to be an associative array). Arrays are represented with square brackets.